# How to retrieve a list of all custom folders in Outlook containing only MailItems?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-2010

I am attempting to retrieve a list of all custom folders created by the user such that I can do a Global Advanced Search.  I only want custom folders with MailItems objects contained within them, so I want to exclude several folders from the list (e.g. RSS Feeds, Quick Step Settings, Suggested Contacts) which come standard in a outlook store.

First, this question is very similiar to questions asked below, but the selected answers did not address custom folders--just all folders.

- [Get list of all Outlook Custom Folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14825647/get-list-of-all-outlook-custom-folders?rq=1)
- [Get list of all Outlook folders and subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10423989/get-list-of-all-outlook-folders-and-subfolders)

**Does anybody know how to retireve a list of custom folders that contain only mailitem objects?**  I have created a fairly large if block to filter out unwanted folders, but I need a more generic approach since this will be deployed on user computers and who-knows-what people do with their outlook folders?

```
if (
    // remove specific search folders from cope
    subfolder.Name == "Quick Step Settings" || subfolder.Name == "News Feed" || subfolder.Name == "Conversation History" || subfolder.Name == "Conversation Action Settings" ||

    // remove unwanted default folders from returning expiring items
    subfolder.FolderPath == Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar).FolderPath ||
    subfolder.FolderPath == Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderConflicts).FolderPath ||
    subfolder.FolderPath == Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts).FolderPath ||
    subfolder.FolderPath == Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDeletedItems).FolderPath ||
    subfolder.FolderPath == Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderJournal).FolderPath ||
    subfolder.FolderPath == Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderRssFeeds).FolderPath ||
    subfolder.FolderPath == Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSuggestedContacts).FolderPath ||
    subfolder.FolderPath == Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSyncIssues).FolderPath ||
    subfolder.FolderPath == Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderServerFailures).FolderPath ||
    subfolder.FolderPath == Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderJunk).FolderPath ||
    subfolder.FolderPath == Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderLocalFailures).FolderPath ||
    subfolder.FolderPath == Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderTasks).FolderPath ||

    // eliminate certain custom folders with unwanted default types
    subfolder.DefaultItemType == Outlook.OlItemType.olContactItem || subfolder.DefaultItemType == Outlook.OlItemType.olJournalItem
    || subfolder.DefaultItemType == Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem || subfolder.DefaultItemType == Outlook.OlItemType.olDistributionListItem
    || subfolder.DefaultItemType == Outlook.OlItemType.olDistributionListItem
    )
{
    addFolder = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to recursively loop through all folders starting with `Namespace.Folders`. For each folder, check the `DefaultItemType` property. If you want to exclude default mail folders (such as Inbox and Sent Items), compare the folder's entry with with the entry id of the default folders retrieved from `GetDefaultFolder`.